# How to get all values from nested enums?

Tags: swift

Working with my key/value Strings file, I'm looking for a simpler way of pulling out values by passing an enum into a function, which does the lookup and returns that value.

This Strings file can be updated over the network, so my app ships with a Default version. Currently, to get those defaults into memory I iterate over my enums cases and add the strings to a dictionary.

It looks like this:

```
enum StringKeys: String, CaseIterable {
   case string1
   case string2
   case string3
}

func setupDefaults() {
   for key in StringKeys.allCases {
      defaults[key] = stringFile.value(forKey: key)
   }
}

func getValue(for: StringKeys) -> String {
    // stuff here...
}
```

This has all been fine for a while now, however this enum is getting quite large and so autocomplete is less helpful.

What I would like to have is something more like this:

```
enum StringKeys: CaseIterable {
   enum Feature1: String, CaseIterable {
        case title1
        case button1
   }
   enum Feature2: String, CaseIterable {
       case title3
       case toggle1
   }
}
```

Then call my `getValue` function with:

```
titleLabel.text = Strings.getValue(for: StringKeys.Feature1.title1)
```

This is all totally fine too, but I can't work out how to iterate over these nested keys to build the defaults dictionary in a nice clean way.

I tried extending `CaseIterable` to add a little `allCasesRecursive` function. Which Swift wouldn't allow.

I know this can be done by adding a property inside each enum, returning `allCases`, and combining them together at each parent. But that's still a bit messy.

The other option is to not use the enums to set up defaults, and instead just parse the whole file and put that directly into defaults, but I'd much rather the enums decide what goes in the defaults. This also makes it easy to see if any are missing i.e, the default for that key won’t be found, and I can throw an error.

So, basically I want to turn a bunch of nested enums into a flat dictionary. Even just an array of keys would be enough to get me the rest of the way. Is it possible to recursively drill down through nested enums? Could I use Reflection to solve this problem?

I'm also open to other ideas, otherwise I'll just stick with the giant, flat enum.

Comment: What is the parameter type of `Strings.getValue`? Note: It can't be `StringKeys` because then you can't pass anything to it, as `StringKeys` don't actually have any cases. It can't be `Feature1`/`Feature2` either because then you can't pass cases of `Feature2`/`Feature1` to it.

Comment: If you in the end still want an array of keys, why not store your keys in a json file that you store in the main bundle and load when needed. You have a few lines extra to read and decode the join file but after that your code should be pretty clean with only an array to work with.

Comment: Trying to limit the amount of areas I’d need to touch when adding new keys/values. Maybe a build script could create this json file instead, based on whatever is in my nested enums. Just look for all the ‘case’ lines... would nested structs be any better? Can you iterate over static properties in those?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question correctly, maybe this will help

```swift
// Create a protocol
protocol StringKeyValue {}

enum StringKeys: CaseIterable {
    enum Feature1: String, CaseIterable, StringKeyValue {
        case title1
        case button1
    }

    enum Feature2: String, CaseIterable, StringKeyValue {
        case title3
        case toggle1
    }
}

func getValue(for: StringKeyValue) -> String {
    return "hi there"
}

// Maybe this's what you want?
titleLabel.text = getValue(for: StringKeys.Feature1.title1)
```

Comment: OP want to have _all_ keys from the enums available in one collection to iterate over. This isn't relevant.

Comment: Yeah, so I do have a file with all the defaults already, but rather than just loading them right into memory, I only want to load the ones that I have covered with enums(keys), what you have done there is what I want to get to, it’s the flattern-nested-enums bit that I’m struggling with.